# How to sort keys in dictionaire if they have the same value, Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionaire in which the keys are strings and the values are integers. Kind of like this:

```
my_dict = {'100': 1,
           '90': 9,
           '180': 9,
           '65': 11,
           '56': 11,
           '74': 11}
```

I want to sort the keys (that are strings) in the dictionaire if they have the same value.
So basically the expected result would be:

my_dict = {'100': 1,
'180': 9,
'90': 9
'56': 11,
'65': 11,
'74': 11}

Can someone help me on this one?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: `"90" > "180"` is true because python sorts strings with an encoding, probably `utf-8`, and `9` has a bigger value than `1`.

Comment: @PeterWood You certainly can, since Python 3.7. Prior to that, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: @blhsing that's not the same. Sorting is changing the order. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

"90" is > than "180" because these are strings and not numbers. Strings are compared alphabetically, not numerically.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question?